# Accessing index of for loop yields 'undefined' result

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

I'm trying to do a *for loop* to interact with all sheets and with all rows within those sheets. I'm doing it in the following way:

```
function verifyUrls(){
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();  
  for (var i in sheets){

    var values = sheets[i].getDataRange().getValues();  
    for(var n = 0; n < values.length; n++) {
      // URLs are in 4 column, first row is a header
      var urls = values[n+1][3];

      var options = {
        'muteHttpExceptions': true,
        'followRedirects': false
      };
      try {
        var resposta = UrlFetchApp.fetch(urls, options);
        var rangeUrl = sheets[i].getRange([n+2],4) // I want to insert a note in URL cells
        rangeUrl.setNote("NICE")
      } 
      catch(e) {
        var rangeUrl = sheets[i].getRange([n+2],4)
        rangeUrl.setNote("ERROR")
      }
    }
  }   
}
```

But I'm getting error

> TypeError: Cannot read property "3" from undefined (line 7, arquivo "Code").

I know that error is triggered when code loop through second sheet. In first sheet code works fine.

I created a test Spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rwx2BJqjRUiyNQZNxG7npgr3zl_ARudMKjkrsgYhgaA/edit

How could I solve this?

Comment: `var urls = values[n+1][3];` check your data. If it's undefined it means that your data isn't setup how you're assuming it is in your code. we can't solve this since we have no idea what that looks like.

Comment: @zfrisch thanks for your reply. I edited my OP with link to spreadsheet.

Comment: Your for loop conditions are not correct. Either start the row loop at 1, and remove the `n+1` index reference, or stop iterating when `n < values.length - 1`. When `n == values.length - 1` (the last iteration in your question's code), you access index `values[values.length]` which is undefined, since Javascript arrays are 0-base indexed.

Comment: @zfrisch I changed to 'n < values.length - 1' and code seems working fine. Could you post it as answer?

Comment: I think you mean @tehhowch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your iteration scheme is flawed, and accesses out-of-bounds indexes.

Your code:

```
for(var n = 0; n < values.length; n++) {
  var urls = values[n+1][3];
```

This means `n` has values `0, 1, ...., values.length-1`. When you call `values[n + 1][3]`, when `n` has the value `values.length - 1`, this results in accessing `values[values.length]`, which is `undefined` since `values` has data at indices of `0, .. values.length - 1`. Thus, attempting to access the 4th index of the `undefined` object results in the error you received.

The solution is to either change the iteration bounds, or change the array accessing:

```
for(var n = 1; n < values.length; n++) {
  var urls = values[n][3];
```

or

```
for(var n = 0; n < values.length - 1; n++) {
  var urls = values[n + 1][3];
```

An additional solution is to not select the headers in the values array:

```
var values = sheet.getSheetValues(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, sheet.getLastColumn());
```

or pop them after reading them:

```
var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
var headers = values.splice(0, 1);
```

After which the "normal" iteration schema will work as expected:

```
for(var n = 0; n < values.length; n++) {
  /* do stuff with n */
```

Comment: PERFECT! Thank you very much!